# Android loadurl fails to execute javascript

Tags: android, android-webview

I have added a Javascript interface object to a WebView using the `addJavascriptInterface()` method and I am trying to invoke a method on that object using `WebView.loadUrl()`.
The object is a simple class called `JSInterface`.  It has a single method called `echo()` that takes no parameters and returns void.  The URL I am passing to `loadUrl()` is `"javascript:JSInterface.echo()"` (JSInterface is also the interface name I used for `addJavascriptInterface()`).  
When I run the attached app, the `echo()` method never executes.  There are no errors in the logcat or anywhere else.  What do I need to do to invoke `echo()` from Javascript?

This is the activity with all source.

---

It is of course right after I post the question that I figure out what's wrong.  In the attached code I am calling `addJavascriptInterface()` from a thread other than the UI thread.  Moving `addJavascriptInterface()` to `onCreate()` fixes the problem.

---

```
package test.pg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class TestActivity2
  extends Activity
{
  WebView webview;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/invoke.html");
    TimerThread t = new TimerThread(webview);
    t.start();
  }

  class TimerThread
    extends Thread
  {
    long    lastRun;
    WebView appView;

    public TimerThread(WebView appView)
    {
      lastRun = System.currentTimeMillis();
      this.appView = appView;
    }

    public void run()
    {
      try
      {
        while (true)
        {
          if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastRun < 5000)
          {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
          }
          else
          {
            appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "JSInterface");
            InvokerThread t = new InvokerThread(appView);
            t.start();
            lastRun = System.currentTimeMillis();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Log.e("InvokerThread", "exception=" + e.toString(), e);
      }
    }
  }

  class InvokerThread
    extends Thread
  {
    WebView appView;

    public InvokerThread(WebView appView)
    {
      this.appView = appView;
    }

    public void run()
    {
      String function = "javascript:JSInterface.echo()";
      appView.loadUrl(function);
    }
  }

  class JSInterface
  {
    public void echo()
    {
      System.out.println("JSInterface.echo()");
      Log.i("JSInterface", "JSInterface.echo()");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot speak directly to the reason why it isn't working, but I do believe the interface is registered at the page level by the `WebView` and the `loadUrl` method might not be as accepting to executing arbitrary script. However it does raise the question on the need for such a design. Surely if your intent is to call a managed object method and you are already in managed code then asking the `WebView` to invoke the managed interface for you is nothing but an un-needed impedance. If of course your example is purely trivial and proof of concept then then the design argument is moot.

Comment: @Quintin The example is just a proof of concept.  The original goal was to invoke some arbitrary JS function and return its result to the native code.  However, I was running into problems with not being called back at all and hence this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is of course right after I post the question that I figure out what's wrong. In the attached code I am calling addJavascriptInterface() from a thread other than the UI thread. Moving addJavascriptInterface() to onCreate() fixes the problem.